Can I set the redirect URI on google identifier in keyclaok?
I want to implement Google login using Keycloak, but I have multiple tenants and need to configure different redirect URIs in Keycloak. Currently, Keycloak does not allow updating the redirect URI for the Google identity provider. Is there a way to achieve this?
enter image description here
